# socket and thread segmentation fault in c language

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, pthreads

i'm working to a client/server application in c language for a university project. basically the client process will send server process some command with the given parameter in a thread:

-store x y (the server save in node of a list x and y)
-search x (search if a node with x value matching the given x exists in the list)
-corrupt x z (change the y-value of the node with the x value matching given x)
-list (simply make the server print the whole list).

the problem is that every command works except for list, every time i send list from the client it gave me segmentation fault ( or stack smashing sometimes ) i think it's a thread fault because if i make the main thread execute the commands everything works as well. strace show that the fault maybe is in the accept function.
this is the server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#define CMD_BUF 20
#define BYTE_CMD_BUF 20*sizeof(char)



typedef struct nodo
{
    char x[8];
    char y[8];
    struct nodo* next;
}nodo;

typedef nodo* lista;



lista listalocale=NULL;


//////////////////////////////////////////////operazioni su lista

lista save(char* x,char* y,lista head)
{
    if(!head)
    {
        head=malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        strcpy(head->x,x);
        strcpy(head->y,y);
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else head->next=save(x,y,head->next);
    return head;
}


void printList(lista head)
{
    char buffer[22];
    sprintf(buffer,"(%s,%s)->",head->x,head->y);
    write(1,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if(head->next) printList(head->next);
    else write(1,"NULL",4);
}



int isPresent(char* x,lista head)
{
    if(!head) return 0;
    else if(!strcmp(head->x,x)) return 1;
    return isPresent(x,head->next);
}



void changeValue(char* x,char* z,lista head)
{
    if(!head) return;
    else if(!strcmp(head->x,x)) strcpy(head->y,z);
    else changeValue(x,z,head->next);
    return;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////elaborazione e gestione comandi
void formatMessage(char* buff,char* comm, char* val1, char* val2)
{
    comm[0]=buff[0];
    comm[1]=buff[1];
    comm[2]='\0';

    int i=3, j=0;
    while (buff[i]!=' ' & buff[i]!='_') val1[j++]=buff[i++];
    val1[j]='\0';

    j=0;
    while (buff[i]!='_') val2[j++]=buff[i++];
    val2[j]='\0';   
}


void *processCommandServer(void *arg)
{
    char buff[20],com[3],p1[8],p2[8];
    int sd=*(int*)arg;


    if( read(sd,buff,BYTE_CMD_BUF)<1 ) perror("COMANDO SCONOSCIUTO");

    formatMessage(buff,com,p1,p2);


    if(!strcmp(com,"li")) printList(listalocale);
    else if(!strcmp(com,"se")) isPresent(p1,listalocale);
    else if(!strcmp(com,"st")) listalocale=save(p1,p2,listalocale);
    else if(!strcmp(com,"co")) changeValue(p1,p2,listalocale);
    return NULL;
} 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// gestione connessione

void assegnaIndirizzo(int sd,char* indirizzo,int porta)
{
    struct sockaddr_in  server;

     server.sin_family=AF_INET;
     server.sin_port=htons(porta);
     server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(indirizzo);

    if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&server , sizeof( server))<0) 
        perror("ERRORE CONNESSIONE");
}


int creaSocketServer(char* indirizzo,int porta)
{
    int sd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sd<=0) perror("ERRORE CREAZIONE");
    else assegnaIndirizzo(sd,indirizzo,porta);

    return sd;
}


int waitConnection(int sd)
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    socklen_t l=sizeof(address);
    int sd2;
    pthread_t tid=0;

    listen(sd,5);

    sd2=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&address,&l);                  //commenta se vuoi eliminare thread
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,processCommandServer,(void*) &sd2);   //commenta se vuoi eliminare thread

    while(1)
    {
        sd2=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&address,&l);
        //processCommandServer((void*)&sd2);                            //scommenta se vuoi eliminare thread
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);                                         //commenta se vuoi eliminare thread
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,processCommandServer,(void*) &sd2);    //commenta se vuoi eliminare thread
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sd=creaSocketServer("192.168.1.195",atoi(argv[1]));
    waitConnection(sd);
}
```

and this is the client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define CMD_BUF 20
#define BYTE_CMD_BUF 20*sizeof(char)


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////gestione connessioni
void sendData(int sd, char* comando)
{
    int res=write(sd,comando,strlen(comando)*sizeof(char));     //invia comando

    if(res > 0) write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Message Delivered\n",sizeof("Message Delivered\n"));   //controlla esito invio comando
    else perror("ERROR");
}

void connettiSocket(int sd,const char* indirizzo,int porta)
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;   

    client.sin_family=AF_INET;                      //imposta connessione tcp
    client.sin_port=htons(porta);                   //imposta porta
    client.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(indirizzo);    //imposta indirizzo

    if( connect(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizeof(client)) <0 )  //si connette a client e controlla errori 
        perror("ERRORE CONNESSIONE");
}

int creaSocketClient(const char* indirizzo,int porta)
{
    int sd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);       //crea socket

    if(sd<=0) perror("ERRORE CREAZIONE");       //controlla errori
    else connettiSocket(sd,indirizzo, porta);

    return sd;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////comandi
void store(const char* x, const char* y,const char* ip, int porta)
{
    int sd=creaSocketClient(ip,porta);  //crea connessione

    char cmd[CMD_BUF];                  //buffer comando
    sprintf(cmd,"st %s %s_",x,y);       //formatta comando

    sendData(sd,cmd);                   
}

void corrupt(const char* x, const char* z,const char* ip, int porta) //vedi store
{
    int sd=creaSocketClient(ip,porta);

    char cmd[CMD_BUF];
    sprintf(cmd,"co %s %s_",x,z);

    sendData(sd,cmd);
}

void search(const char* x,const char* ip, int porta)//vedi store
{
    int sd=creaSocketClient(ip,porta);

    char cmd[CMD_BUF];
    sprintf(cmd,"se %s_",x);

    sendData(sd,cmd);
}

void list(const char* ip, int porta)//vedi store
{
    int sd=creaSocketClient(ip,porta);

    char cmd[CMD_BUF];
    sprintf(cmd,"li_");

    sendData(sd,cmd);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
         if(!strcmp(argv[3],"store")   & argc==6) store(argv[4],argv[5],argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    else if(!strcmp(argv[3],"corrupt") & argc==6) corrupt(argv[4],argv[5],argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    else if(!strcmp(argv[3],"search")  & argc==5) search(argv[4],argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    else if(!strcmp(argv[3],"list")    & argc==4) list(argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    else perror("comando non valido");  
}
```

this is the strace output if i send 2 store command and 1 list command:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out", "5900"], 0x7ffff0e72298 /* 25 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x555c05424000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd14dbd370) = -1 EINVAL (Argomento non valido)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=228153, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 228153, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f066cef9000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340f\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=155408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f066cef7000
lseek(3, 808, SEEK_SET)                 = 808
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
mmap(NULL, 131528, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f066ced6000
mmap(0x7f066cedc000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f066cedc000
mmap(0x7f066ceeb000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f066ceeb000
mmap(0x7f066cef1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a000) = 0x7f066cef1000
mmap(0x7f066cef3000, 12744, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f066cef3000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000C\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
lseek(3, 792, SEEK_SET)                 = 792
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\201\336\t\36\251c\324\233E\371SoK\5H\334"..., 68) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2136840, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 792, SEEK_SET)                 = 792
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\201\336\t\36\251c\324\233E\371SoK\5H\334"..., 68) = 68
lseek(3, 864, SEEK_SET)                 = 864
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
mmap(NULL, 1848896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f066cd12000
mprotect(0x7f066cd34000, 1671168, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f066cd34000, 1355776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f066cd34000
mmap(0x7f066ce7f000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16d000) = 0x7f066ce7f000
mmap(0x7f066cecc000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b9000) = 0x7f066cecc000
mmap(0x7f066ced2000, 13888, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f066ced2000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f066cd0f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f066cd0f740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f066cecc000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f066cef1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x555c0363d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f066cf5a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f066cef9000, 228153)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f066cd0fa10)         = 10560
set_robust_list(0x7f066cd0fa20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f066cedc130, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f066cee83c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f066cedc1d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f066cee83c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5900), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.195")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60902), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.195")}, [16]) = 4
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f066c50e000
mprotect(0x7f066c50f000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x555c05424000
brk(0x555c05445000)                     = 0x555c05445000
clone(child_stack=0x7f066cd0dfb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0, tls=0x7f066cd0e700, child_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0) = 10562
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60904), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.195")}, [16]) = 5
clone(child_stack=0x7f066cd0dfb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0, tls=0x7f066cd0e700, child_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0) = 10564
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60906), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.195")}, [16]) = 6
clone(child_stack=0x7f066cd0dfb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0, tls=0x7f066cd0e700, child_tidptr=0x7f066cd0e9d0) = 10566
accept(3,  <unfinished ...>)            = ?
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: `!strcmp(...) & argc==4`  - `&` is executed first, then `==`, so it's `(!strcmp(...) & argc) == 4`. Probably you want `&&`.

Comment: I don't see a "smoking gun" bug in your code, but keep in in mind that using `sprintf()` with the %s option is a bit risky, since the %s can expand out to (potentially) a large number of characters if the string-argument it represents is long.  That can easily make `sprintf()` write past the end of the target array, causing stack corruption, especially if the target array's size is small (yours is apparently only 20 bytes long?). You might want to consider using `snprintf()` instead, so that if the generated string is too large for the array, at least it won't corrupt the stack.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the main thread generally is given a very large amount of stack space to work with (e.g. often practically limited only by available RAM), while other threads often get only a small/fixed amount of stack space (sometimes as little as 4KB per thread).  So if you are declaring a large amount of data on the stack somewhere, that might explain why it works from the main thread but crashes when run on other threads.  (I didn't see any evidence of that in the code you posted, but your description of the entry conditions reminded me of that)

Comment: i change every & in && and fixed the size of string with snprintf but nothing work ... it's so strange

Answer (score 0):

the error was in the formatMessage function, list got no parameter so it have 3 character the function start copying the command(first 2 char) and the jump to the 4th that is out of the list command array bound. As well your tips where very useful